# Position of UIActivityViewController changed on changing orientation of device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, constraints, uiactivityindicatorview

I’m building an article reading app.I implemented UIActivityViewController in UITableViewController programmatically.I am facing 
an issue when i change the orientation of device the position of UIActivityViewController  changed.

This my code:

```
       indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
       if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
        {
            indicator.center = CGPointMake(350, 300);
            [self.tableView addSubview:indicator];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
             [indicator layoutIfNeeded];
          }

     else{

            indicator.center = CGPointMake(200, 400);
            [self.tableView addSubview:indicator];
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;

        }
```

If it is possible by applying constraints programmatically,how i can do this.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could have `indicator.center = self.tableview.center` and call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` upon orientation. 
Anyway I've just noticed something that looks odd. You do `[self.view addSubview:indicator]` but then you do `[indicator bringSubviewToFront:self.view]`, I don't actually recall what the behaviour of this could be (probably nothing) but should be the other way round because indicator is subview of your self.view. 
Furthermore, why do you add indicator twice (once for tableView and once for view) in the body of the else statement?

**EDIT:**

Or you could use Autolayout and forget about frames. Something like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *centerX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:indicator
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self.tableView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:centerX];
```

And do the same for centerY.

Comment: @thanks Dan i have edited my code above.[self.view layoutIfNeeded] this make no effect.

Comment: Would be good to know where is your code placed. Because I don't see how it could react to any orientation change. You are deciding which centre to apply only once when you create the indicator and add it to the view hierarchy. Up to iOS 7 you could have used 
`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` on iOS 8 this is deprecated and you should use `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the position of the activityIndicator when it's first created and added to the view hierarchy. But you're not updating that position upon rotation.

You could achieve this update by either using constraints (a centerX and centerY constraint) as noted here by another responder, or overriding layoutSubviews and setting the center point of the activityIndicator to the center of the tableView.

Something like:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.tableView.center;
}
```